# ruby on rails undefined method `_delete' in rails version 2.3.15 works fine with 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, hosting

ruby on rails undefined method `_delete' in rails version 2.3.15 works fine with 2.3.5

```
ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `_delete' for #<Exam:0x709f33664f48>) on line #105 of app/views/exam/_exam_marks_form.erb:
102:         <td class="col-1">
103:           <div class="label-field-pair2">
104:             <div class="text-input-bg2">
105:               <%= exam_form.check_box :_delete %>
106:             </div>
107:           </div>
108:         </td>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails changed this around the 2.3.8 timeframe.  Change :_delete to :_destroy and you should be good.